# Is there a way to run "eslint --fix" and output the fixes to another file?

Tags: eslint

Is there a way to run eslint --fix foo.js and not do the fixes in-place?
I want the fixed file to be saved in another file.
Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such option in cli. And I expect this feature will never be added. If you really need the fixed code to be written to another file, you can use eslint's [node api](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/nodejs-api#nodejs-api) to pull together a customized solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this now.

I just ran the following command, using  ESLint-formatters [ESLint-formatters](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/formatters/)

`npx eslint . --fix --format json --output-file eslintreport.json`

There are also packages out there like [ESLint Output](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-output) that can help you achieve expanded functionality beyond what's supported by formatters in the latest ESLint cli.

See here as well: [Helpful SO Post with more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58391647/eslint-output-to-file-and-console-at-the-same-time)

Comment: Dropping `--fix` avoided applying the fix to the current file while still saving the fixes to the report file