# ESLint output to file and console at the same time

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, eslint

By default ESLint will print it's results to standard output. If you add the output option, it will redirect the output to a file. So far so good, but is there a way for it to do both?

We need the file output for GitLab to parse the results and display them in the UI, but some of our developers can't be bothered to change the way they do things and want to look at the output instead.

Is there an out-of-the-box way to get both or is my only chance to write my own script for running ESLint using the CLIEngine Node stuff mentioned in their documentation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So, after some research I think I found the answer myself.

There's basically 2 ways to have output on both console and file at the same time:

1. The easy way is by using this JavaScript package called [ESLint Output](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-output).
2. The more complicated way is basically building said package yourself. You have to create a JavaScript file which you will run instead of ESLint and import/require ESLint in that file. By importing ESLint as a package instead of running it directly you can then run ESLint using Node's CLIEngine on your files to be linted and store the output in a variable. That output can then be saved to a file and printed again.

Hopefully, to no one's surprise, the methodology described in Option 2 is exactly what the package in Option 1 does: wrapping option 2 in an easy to understand config file and gathering all the configuration from the default `eslintrc` file for you.

Answer (score 14):

Just write ESLint result into file and then read it by using one of [ESLint-formatters](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/formatters/):

```sh
npx eslint ./cartridges/ --format json --output-file result.json
node -p "require('./node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/formatters/unix.js')(require('./result.json'))"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with [eslint-html-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-html-reporter). When you'd like to have results from Terminal **and** export this into an **.html** file then the output from Terminal becomes a bit less pretty (which is not the case if it's done only in one of those), but it's doable by running:

`./node_modules/.bin/eslint --ext .jsx . & ./node_modules/.bin/eslint --ext .jsx . -f node_modules/eslint-html-reporter/reporter.js -o report.html` (in this example it looks recursively for `.jsx` file in your project's folder).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the file output needs to be in JUnit style XML for Gitlab to parse the test results. If we'd add fancy HTML output to a file, we'd have yet another problem needing to create two separate file outputs, each with a different format.

Comment: This runs eslint twice

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and worked around by running eslint twice.

Created a shell script with

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
node_modules/.bin/eslint --quiet \
    --max-warnings 100 \
    -o eslint-output.$1 \
    -f $1 '*/**/*.{js,ts,tsx}'
```

Then call the script twice thru Jenkins:

```
steps {
    echo 'Rodando ESLint...' 
    sh("""
        yarn install
        ./eslint.sh junit || true
        ./eslint.sh codeframe || true
    """)

    junit(
        allowEmptyResults: true,
        healthScaleFactor: 0.0,
        testResults: 'eslint-output.junit'
    )
}
```

Comment: But now your ESLint step in the pipeline uses twice the time and resources and that just for reformatting the output that's already there in a machine-readable format and could easily be transformed to both formats if ESLint would want to.

Answer (score -1):

To generate the file for report:

eslint src/ --format json --output-file eslintreport.json

Comment: > By default ESLint will print it's results to standard output. If you add the output option, it will redirect the output to a file. So far so good, but is there a way for it to do both?
..............
I know ESLint can output it's report as a File, but when it does that, it will ONLY output to the file and not print anything to stdout. That's the problem I was trying to solve, your solution is not helpful at all.